# How to get a single combined string out of multiple consecutive spans with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an address in a block of html that has all it's parts divided between multiple spans. I want the address as a single string, how do I strip out the spans?

```
<div class="AddressInfo">
 <span class="AddressNumber">2222 </span>
 <span class="AddressDirection"></span>
 <span class="AddressName">Turtle Creek Boulevard</span>
 <span class="AddressUnitNumber">5E</span>
 <span class="EndAddressComma">,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

I don't want the comma and I don't need any empty spans, just the text as one single string in a new var.

I've gotten as far as grabbing AddressInfo by getElementsByClassName so now I have this html block to work with. If there's a better way I'd be very grateful to learn it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, perhaps get the `innerText` of the `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the `textContent` of the containing `<div>`, and trim it and remove commas and whatever else you don't want:

```js
const { textContent } = document.querySelector('.AddressInfo');
const trimmed = textContent.trim().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(trimmed);
```

```html
<div class="AddressInfo">
 <span class="AddressNumber">2222 </span>
 <span class="AddressDirection"></span>
 <span class="AddressName">Turtle Creek Boulevard</span>
 <span class="AddressUnitNumber">5E</span>
 <span class="EndAddressComma">,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use `innerText`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('AddressInfo')[0].innerText.replace(/,/g, '')
```

Comment: This is simple and great except it still leaves in the comma which i don't need.

Comment: Oh I see, perhaps use `replace` to remove the unwanted chars.